# Convert java.util.Date to different time zone requested

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, timezone, java.util.date

Depending on a request url, I have to convert a Date to different requested time zone and return date and time as String. I am using java 8 with spring boot and mongo 3.2

So inside the service method, I first set the time zone as below,

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE))
```

But I notice, it will change the time zone of whole java application. So even the method exit, the time zone would be remain the time zone I set previously.

So instead `setDefault` method level, I set it specifically in the `SimpleDateFormat` as below,

(assignment is a Assignmet document class having `java.util.Date` as a property named assignmentEndDate which map to a mongodb collection. In mongo db assignmentEndDate is store as UTC)

```
   java.text.DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
   Date assignmentEndDate = assignment.getAssignmentEndDate();
   formatter.format(assignmentEndDate);
```

This way it wont change the application level time zone. Is this the correct approach for such scenario?

Comment: Is there a reason you're constrained to `java.util.Date` and can't use the `java.time` package?

Comment: your code is correct for the older java date/time apis.

Comment: @jtahlborn So your recommendation is to use java.time API's instead of java.util.Date?

Comment: if you have the ability to use the newer apis, then that probably would make sense.  otherwise, the code you have should work just fine.

Comment: @jtahlborn Thanks. But dont you think change to the application level time zone only when we change the time zone for specific request is a issue

Comment: @JoeC No particular reason. I am thinking of refactor those to java.time

Comment: maybe i don't understand what you are asking.  setting the application default timezone is absolutely incorrect.  your second code block where you change the timezone for a specific response is the correct way to handle such a situation.

Comment: @jtahlborn yes your right. so first code block was what i had before add second code block. So once I realize TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE)) will change the application level time zone, I use the second code block.

Comment: @jtahlborn Could you please answer my this question also.  In another scenario I have to do something like I am compare the current date time with another date. So I am using java.util.Date before method.  Since we have application servers distribute two zones, I set using the TimeZone.setDefault(timezone) and use the before method. Eg: TimeZone.setDefault(timezone);

Comment: Date instances do not have a timezone.  they are always UTC.  so setting the timezone in order to compare two Date instances doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jtahlborn Well when I just initialize a Date object, I find that It will assign hour, minutes etc with consider current server time zone and not the UTC.  May be that confusion is the reason those getHour etc API's are depricated. But the fastTime field which save date time in milliseconds save the value always in UTC know?  So when use before() method, Date object use the value in fastTime field, we dont have to set the TImeZone to UTC explicitly know?

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of new date time api included in Java 8.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago");
```

You can start with ***[Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)***, a java util date equalivent.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = instant.atZone(zoneId);
```

Or

You can also start with 
 using ***[ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)***

You can  take datetime as ***[LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)***, time zone agnostic class and  convert to ZonedDateTime.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId);
```

You can easliy switch betweeen old date time classes & new time by accessing the helper methods on each of the new/old date time classes.

Change to java util date while saving to mongo database

```
//From ZonedDateTime to java util date.
Date oldDate = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());

//From Instant to java util date
Date oldDate = Date.from(instant);

//From Date to Instant.
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

All the new date time api have default formatter built into it.

```
//2007-12-03T10:15:30-06:00[America/Chicago]
String zonedDatetime = zonedDateTime.toString();
```

For specfic format you can always pass the ***[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)*** to the below method.

```
zonedDateTime.format(formatter)
```